# Multiple Parameter using CASE in OLEDB Command SSIS

Tags: parameters, ssis, sql-server-2012, multiple-conditions, oledbcommand

I am trying to update a table in SSIS using OLEDB Command.
The objective is to update `[Value]` according to condition matched from `ID_1` and `ID_2`.
The `[Value]` column is to be updated from different Columns (hence the '?') using Column Mappings of the SSIS OLEDB Command.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET [Value] = CASE
WHEN ID_1 = 'A' AND ID_2 = '1' THEN ?
WHEN ID_1 = 'B' AND ID_2 = '2' THEN ?
ELSE [Value]
END
```

It should look something like this:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1234 |
| B | 2 | 5678 |

However, it throws an error "The parameter type cannot be deduced because a single expression contains two untyped parameters, '@P1' and '@P2'.

I have tried the solutions here: [Multiple parameters in a query using a OLE DB COMMAND in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907316/multiple-parameters-in-a-query-using-a-ole-db-command-in-ssis) and [Update multiple rows with multiple 'where' clauses for each individual row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344120/update-multiple-rows-with-multiple-where-clauses-for-each-individual-row)

I have tried declaring the parameters which throws an error "The variable name '@P1' has already been declared..." and "The undeclared parameter '@P1' is used more than once in the batch being analyzed."

```
DECLARE @P1 AS DECIMAL(15,4) = ?
DECLATE @P2 AS DECIMAL(15,4) = ?

UPDATE MyTable
SET [Value] = CASE
WHEN ID_1 = 'A' AND ID_2 = '1' THEN @P1
WHEN ID_1 = 'B' AND ID_2 = '2' THEN @P2
ELSE [Value]
END
```

However, none of the workarounds have worked for me. Is there any other way to achieve this result?
Can someone please help me out here? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try `WHEN ID_1 = 'A' AND ID_2 = '1' THEN CAST(? as DECIMAL(15,4)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RBarryYoung :) this worked. 
Appreciate it!